# Cannot connect Mass Transit to a Managed Identity in an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, masstransit, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to configure Mass Transit to allow me to use a User Assigned Managed Identity instead of needing to store the connection string in the local settings of my Azure Function.

I have gathered there is a secondary parameter that should be used to achieve this on the AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions method. I have done this below:

```
        builder.Services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ConsumerNamespace>();

        }, "ServiceBus", (context, configurator) =>
        {
            string clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(CommonConstants.ConfigSettingsKeys.ManagedIdentityClientId);

            var settings = new HostSettings
            {
                ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://mytestservicebus.servicebus.windows.net"),
                TokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId })
            };
            configurator.Host(settings);
        });
```

The problem is that the code passed in for the first parameter gets called, but the code that gets passed in to get excecuted as the final paramter never gets called. Is there something else I need to set here to make sure the code gets called?

I am using version 7.3.1 of Mass Transit.

Thank you.

Comment: You might try just removing the `TokenCredential = ` since the Azure SDK will try to figure it out on its own when not specified.

Comment: Hi Chris. I think because we are using a User Assigned Managed Identity we need it because we need to specify the client Id, this is how we have used DefaultAzureCredential elsewhere for all our other connections.

Is what I am trying to do here right? When running this locally (I have not tried remote) should the code setting the client id not at least be getting hit?

I've looked at the internal method and seen that "configureBus?.Invoke" should get called as part of "UsingAzureServiceBus" but it just does not seem to in my case.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Yeah, it looks to me like the cause is because the underlying method "UsingAzureServiceBus" (within "AddMassTransit" which should invoke the configureBus method) never gets called. Is there something I can modify here so that it does?

Comment: You can see exactly what is used in the [code](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/Transports/MassTransit.WebJobs.ServiceBusIntegration/AzureFunctionsBusConfigurationExtensions.cs#L46). Not sure what to tell you otherwise.